# xslt - creating node from text

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to create a template that allows me to generate a new element from the text in the document. For example if the xml input is

```
<c>
  <a>foo</a>
  <b>bar</b>
</c>
```

I want to create a stylesheet which generates the following output:

```
<c>
  <a><el att="foo"></a>
  <b><el att="bar></b>
</c>
```

I write the following template

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
<xsl:element name="el">
  <xsl:attribute name="att"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

But the match doesn't work- it consider "text" also other the space between the end of a tag and the beginning of the other tag and the value of the attribute is not set. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`xsl:strip-space`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#strip) to ignore insignificant whitespace.

Also, in your template your context is already `text()`, so use `.` ([short for `self::node()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#path-abbrev)) or `normalize-space()`.

Example (slightly simplified by using an [AVT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates)) ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" priority="1">
    <el att="{.}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If the xml input was `<c> foo <a>...` (text in the root node) it gives me  `<el att="&#xA;foo&#xA;"/>` How can I solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user8864215 - Use `normalize-space()` (like `<el att="{normalize-space()}"/>`). I updated my answer. Also notice I added a `priority` attribute to resolve any ambiguous template matches.